# pass selenium webdriver as argoument for python program

Tags: python, selenium

i want to run a python program `first.py` by another program and pass the `webdriver
element` as an argoument using `subprocess` doing so:

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver.exe")
    process = subprocess.Popen(["python.exe", 'first.py', driver], shell=False)
```

but python refuses to pass a `webdriver element` as an `argoument`
and gives this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\bo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/bo/Desktop/instagrambot/run_bot.py", line 23, in <lambda>
run_button = tk.Button(root , text="Run", command=lambda: Run())
File "C:/Users/bo/Desktop/instagrambot/run_bot.py", line 12, in Run
close_fds=True)
File "C:\Users\bo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\bo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1119, in _execute_child
args = list2cmdline(args)
File "C:\Users\bo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 530, in list2cmdline
needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'WebDriver' is not iterable
```

I'm working on windows 10 and python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to the `subprocess.Popen` call are supposed to be strings whereas you are passing a Python object. This is why you are getting an iteration error - Python attempts to parse the string arguments (that are separated either with a space or a tab) and fails when he gets a Python object.

You have to unfortunately to rethink your strategy. You could construct the `driver` within the `first.py` module or have a separate Python module which you could import to get a `driver` set up when executing the `first.py` module.

Comment: my problem is that when i want to call the process.terminate() function the `"first.py"` is closed but not the driver, i tried to put the driver.quit() function in a finally block but it doesn't work neither, the process.terminate() close the program bypassing the finally block and le tthe driver open

Comment: Why do you need to use the `subprocess` in the first place? I have been always using Selenium in a plain Python module closing the driver as the last thing, never had a problem

Comment: If you are afraid your script may raise an unexpected exception, then you could wrap your web driver interaction code into the `try/except/finally` block with the driver closing operation put into the `finally` so the web browser will always close

Comment: becouse i'm working with many python files toghether and need to start and close programs from a main program

Comment: yeah i placed the driver closing operetion in `try/except/finally` block but the `process.terminate()` operetion bypass it and don't understant why

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you cannot construct driver in the module where your driver code interaction lives? Or just import the modules instead of using `subprocess`? It would be much easier to debug and maintain the code when you can navigate all around the code without having some calls happening.

Comment: i built the driver in the module where the driver code interaction lives but the problem is that i'd like to call the `first.py` program by `subprocess.popen` let the code work and after call `process.terminate()` for end the program and close the driver, but the file where i call the start of `first.py` doesn't have access to the `driver element` built in `first.py` so it can't close the driver but only the program

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840396/execute-finally-when-subprocess-process-terminate-is-called?noredirect=1#comment96454447_54840396

Comment: I still don't understand why you would need to use the subprocess instead building a script that will import the needed modules and get the work done